# Register control after page initialized ASP.NET AJAX

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I want to add user controls incrementally and dynamically to a page that is already loaded using AJAX and not postback.  My problem is that the control is loaded after the user clicks a button on the page.  If just clicked once everything is fine.  But if the button is clicked again the first control is removed.  After much research I believe that it is because the first control wasn't registered with the page when it was initialized.

Is there a way to register the control with the page after the page has been loaded and initialized?

Answer (score 0):

You have to recreate dynamically created controls on postbacks with the same ID as before. Therefore you need to store the number of already created controls, a good place is the ViewState. By the way, this works the same as without AJAX.

For example:

**aspx**:

```
<asp:Button type="button" id="BtnAddButton" runat="server" Text="Add Button" />    
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1">
    <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:Panel ID="ButtonPanel" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="BtnAddButton" />
    </Triggers>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Codebehind**:

```
Public Property ButtonCount As Int32
    Get
        Dim VS_ButtonCount = ViewState("ButtonCount")
        If VS_ButtonCount Is Nothing Then
            ViewState("ButtonCount") = 0
        End If
        Return DirectCast(ViewState("ButtonCount"), Int32)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Int32)
        ViewState("ButtonCount") = value
    End Set
End Property

Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    For i As Int32 = 1 To Me.ButtonCount
        Dim btn As New Button
        btn.ID = "Button_" & i
        btn.Text = btn.ID
        AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf ButtonClick
        Me.ButtonPanel.Controls.Add(btn)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim btn = DirectCast(sender, Button)
End Sub

Protected Sub BtnAddButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles BtnAddButton.Click
    Me.ButtonCount += 1
    Dim btn As New Button
    btn.ID = "Button_" & ButtonCount
    btn.Text = btn.ID
    AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf ButtonClick
    Me.ButtonPanel.Controls.Add(btn)
End Sub
```